# which one of the following statement are/is True $?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A$ and $ B$ be  $n \times  n$    matrix.

which  one  of the  following statement are/is   True $?$

$a)$ if  $A^n = 0$ for  some $ n $,  then  $\det A  =  0$.

$b)$ if A and  B have  the same  characteristic  polynomial, then they  are similar.

$c)$ if   the eigenvalues  of $A$ are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\dots,\lambda_n$, then  A is similar 
to the

diagonal matrix diag($\lambda_1 ,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\dots,\lambda_n$)

My answer : all options a, b  and c..

For  option a),  take  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$

For  option b),  take  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and   $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$

For option c), take   $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Is it True ??....

Comment: a) is right, b) and c) are wrong. You found a counterexample for b). For c), you might find a counterexample. There is no counterexample for a), you should show that the statement is true for *any* $n\times n$ matrix

Comment: Hint for a) : $\det(AB)=\det(A) \det(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is true for a  nilpotent matrix has all eigenvalues zero. Since det$A$ is equal to the product of eigenvalue, det$A=0$.

(b) is not true. Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Both have the same characteristics polynomial but  $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

(c) is not true in general. It is true when $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix having eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$.